# Tornado UI Module

Tags: tornado

I'm using Tornado and have a html file that I want to use as the content for an email. The way i'm emailing is to use a `os.system()` command. However I need to dynamically create a section of the html file. I have been reading about UI modules. I'm wondering if i can use the UI module to pass arguments to dynamically create a html page and then retrieve this as a string?

I've beem using the standard templates within my html to render pages in html. E.g.

```
class xxx(BaseHandler):
   async def get(self):
    self.render("xxx.html",
                  s=sss,
                  u=user,
                  p="somethingXXX")
```

I want to use the same template functionality however be able to retrieve the string? Is this possible?

Comment: I realised it might be better to use BeautifulSoup for this task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`RequestHandler.render_string`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.render_string) method. This is similar to `render`, but it returns the string to the caller instead of writing it as the HTTP response.

`UIModules` are different - they're a way of organizing things *within* your templates, with special features for javascript/css dependencies (and they only work with `render`, not `render_string`).